# Get node parent of defined type using xpath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

i will give an example of the problem i have. My XML is like this

```
<root>
  <child Name = "child1">
  <node>
  <element1>Value1</element1>
  <element2>Value2</element2>
  </node>
  </child>
  <child Name = "child2">
  <element1>Value1</element1>
  <element2>Value2</element2>
  <element3>Value3</element3>
  </child>
</root>
```

I have xpath expression that returns all "element2" nodes. Then i want to for every node of type "element2" to find the node of type "child" that contains it. The problem is that between these two nodes there can be from 1 to n different nodes so i can't just use "..". Is there something like "//" that will look up instead of down

I have some basic knowledge of xpath and according http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp "..' returns current node parent the problem is that the current node is "element2" and the problem is that the xml is dynamic comes from third party library so i can have xml like this

```
<child Name = "child1">
  <node>
  <element1>Value1</element1>
  </node>
</child>
```

or like this

```
<child Name = "child1">
  <node1>
   <node2>
    <node3>
     <element1>Value1</element1>
     <element2>Value2</element2>
    </node3>
   </node2>
  </node1>
</child>
```

There can be more then 3 nodes between "element" and child an the number of nodes vary form 1 to 20. Please give me an example of just one xpath query to get the "child" node in both cases using just ".."

Best Regards,
Iordan

Comment: Using the abbreviation `..` is equivalent to using the `parent::` axis.

Your statement that you can't use `..` is simply wrong. Please, verify your statements with examples so that you'll significantly decrease the number of question asked with false and misleading statements. It won't hurt to learn just a little bit XPath either.

Comment: Hi, it is written in my question. Between "element2" and "child" there cloud be from 1 to n other nodes so i don't know who many times i need to use ".." to get to "child"

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev i have edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your current context is the `element2` element? Use the `parent` [axis](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp):

```
parent::child/@Name
```

That will get the parent of the current element, named `child`, and get its attribute `Name`.

If you're not in the context of `element2` and you want to find all `child` elements with `element2` children, you need this one instead:

```
child[element2]
```

Comment: @IordanTanev: BTW, the shortcut for `parent::*` is `..`, so `../@Name` would work perfectly as well.

Answer (score 4):

The ancestor xpath axis is what you are looking for:

```
element2/ancestor::child
```

The ancestor axis returns all the elements that contain the context element, going upward.

Answer (score 3):

Use the .. operator.